# Using Django views queries in graphene resolvers

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

How can I use my django view queries in graphene resolvers as queries?

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return CustomerModel.objects.for_entity(
        entity_slug=self.kwargs['entity_slug'],
        user_model=self.request.user
    ).order_by('-updated')
```

I tried this but it did not work

```
class CustomerList(DjangoObjectType):
"""testing API
"""
class Meta:
    model = CustomerModel
    fields = ("email",)
class CustomerQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
all_customers = graphene.List(CustomerList)

def resolve_all_customers(self, root, **kwargs):
    return CustomerModel.objects.for_entity.filter(
        entity_slug=self.kwargs['entity_slug'],
        user_model=self.request.user
    ).order_by('-updated')
```

I get this graphql error

> "message": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kwargs'",
> "locations": [
> {
> "line": 2,
> "column": 3
> }

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the arguement in

`all_customers = graphene.List(CustomerList)`

Like this

`all_customers = graphene.List(CustomerList, entity_slug=graphene.String(required=True))`

Complete Code:

```py
class CustomerQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_customers = graphene.List(CustomerList, entity_slug=graphene.String(required=True))

def resolve_all_customers(self, root, **kwargs):
    return CustomerModel.objects.for_entity.filter(
        entity_slug=kwargs.get('entity_slug'),
        user_model=self.request.user
    ).order_by('-updated')
```

To read more, check the [official document](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/objecttypes/#resolverparamgraphqlarguments)

Comment: it works fine but i get {
  "data": {
    "allCustomers": null
  }  
query{
  allCustomers(entitySlug:"Stats") {
    email
    
  }
}

Comment: what is your implementation for class CustomerList(DjangoObjectType):?

Comment: class CustomerList(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerModel
        fields = ("city", "email")

Comment: Why you are using for_entity?
have you tested it without for_entity?

Comment: def for_entity(self, entity_slug: str, user_model):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(
            Q(entity__slug__exact=entity_slug) &
            Q(active=True) &
            (
                    Q(entity__admin=user_model) |
                    Q(entity__managers__in=[user_model])
            )
        )

Comment: The for entity method guarantees that only the customers associated with a specific entity AND specific user permissions are returned

Comment: Try to debug, print the query set result and see what it is showing